# Thymleaf Spring MVC Application Not able to include .css in HTML

Tags: html

I am new to Thymleaf. The following is my folder structure. Here I am not able to include my css file into ".html" file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<title>Hello Spring MVC</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../resources/css/style.css" th:href="@{../resources/css/style.css}" />
 
 
 <style>
  body {
      background-color: lightblue;
  }
 </style>

</head>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working. It is not including CSS because of  ""(double-quotes) are not in compatible.(Copied code from a Blog).

Thanks.